# How to speed up the execution process of Executable file generated by python pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have created a Executable file through pyinstaller and size of the file is `7.7MB`. Once I click on the file to execute it, It is taking almost 25+ Seconds to open the tkinter screen

Code which I am using to generate executable file is as below:

```
from tkinter import *

G = Tk()

G.geometry("500x250")
G.resizable(0, 0)
G.title("Message")

F1 = Frame(G, bg="pink",borderwidth=15, relief=SUNKEN)
F1.pack(side=TOP, fill="x")

l = Label(F1, text="Do Something", font="Arial 24 bold", bg="skyblue")
l.pack(pady=10)

G.mainloop()
```

To generate Executable file I am using below command in virtual environment:

```
pyinstaller --onefile imp.py
```

How can I speedup the Executable file execution process so at-least I can able to open tkinter screen within **2-3 Seconds**?

Thanks for replies. It will be very helpful for me if someone guide me on this.

Comment: For what platform are you building the executable?

Comment: @Iguananaut, building the executable on Windows platform.

Comment: That's unusual.  There may not be anything you can do.  You might have a virus scanner or something like that which is slowing your computer down.